# Recursive adding of elements in a hashset in java does not work though removing does

Tags: java, hashset

I think I have to explain my situation. I am creating a character editor for dungeons and dragons (I am not a nerd). In some place the player is forced to choose feats. So I created a hashset of them. In a recursive function I let the user choose among the BIG amount of possible feats. Then they are removed and the player gets the new feat. I will give you a short code example.

```
void choosefeats(int no_of_feats,Set<String> feats){
    String[] featobjects = feats.toArray(new String[feats.size()]);
    Feat = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a feat", 
        "Feats ",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
        null, featobjects, null
    );
    feats.remove(Feat);
    Feats = Feats + "-" + Feat + "\n";
    --no_of_feats;
    switch (Feat) {
        case "Armor Proficiency(Chain)": 
            isprofchain = true;
            if ((strength >= 13) && (constitution >= 13)) {
                feats.add("Armor Proficiency(Scale)");
            };
            break;
        case "Armor Proficiency(Leather)":
            isprofleather = true;
            break;
        case "Armor Proficiency(Hide)":
            isprofhide = true;
            break;
        case "Armor Proficiency(Plate)":
            isprofplate = true;
            break;
        case "Armor Proficiency(Scale)": 
            isprofscale = true;
            if ((strength >= 15)&&(constitution >= 15)) {
                feats.add("Armor Proficiency(Plate)");
            };
            break;          
    }
    if (no_of_feats != 0) {
        choosefeats(no_of_feats, feats);
    } 
    else return;
}
```

removing the feats seems not be a problem at all. But adding some to the set does not seem to work in the switch case statement. Can you help me???

Comment: Please format the code and question so that it's readable.

Comment: Define "does not seem to work".

Comment: Ahm the set should contain for example "armorproficiency(plate)" if the player gets the prerequisits for it after choosing the scale armor feat. But it seems not to appear in it..

Comment: @RaphaelDenken [This runnable example](https://ideone.com/wEQYca) works properly for me.

Comment: But in case of `"Armor Proficiency(Plate)"` you don't add it to `feats`, do you?

Comment: No but it should be avaiable after choosing "Scale proficiency" and if the player meets the other prerequisits. But it's not. Sad! -Thanks by teh way for answering. As this is just a free time issue.

Comment: BTW... Sorry for my bad English. I'm German!

Comment: Great, I fixed my issue! My code was actually fine. I just forgot to write Chainmail instead of writing Chain in the brackets! Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: After `Feats = Feats + "-" + Feat + "\n"`, none of your switch cases will hit (because none contains a dash, nor a new line). Did you ever check that? Remove is outside of the switch.

Comment: It works now. I figured out that my fault had nothing to do with my function. But thank you for your efforts.